# O que posso fazer para página carregar sem quebrar código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Atualmente, quando carrego a página do meu site, aparece tudo quebrado, sem configuração e depois renderiza tudo, o problema é que isso é pouco interativo pro usuário. 
Já minifiquei os arquivos js/css, a velocidade melhorou, mas ainda continua quebrando o a página, isso pode ser problema no html?

Comment: Qual é a pagina ? Qual erro que da? poderia não me passar o endereço FTP com senha para eu dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigão faz o seguinte, deixa uma div global e da "display:none" assim o html vai carregar mas escondido.
Ai no jquery, vc pega o load do document e remove o display:none.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').css('display','');
})
```

Algo nesse sentido, teste e veja se resolve seu problema.
Se funcionar, favor incluir um loading para deixar isso bacana.

Esse problema ocorre pq o html é carregado e renderizado antes de todo css e jquery, então temos que contornar isso.
Ciclo de vida e renderização.

Comment: da uma olhada o que acontece..http://novo.intercambioglobal.com.br/

Comment: Cara, primeiro seu popover e datepicker ta dando erro, resolve isso.
Segundo, coloca o script do ga no final de tudo na pagina.
Terceiro, tem dois header seu codigo, ta certo isso? ve os templates.

mas nada disso q to falando cria esse problema, apenas dicas.
Aqui ocorreu tambem, ele carrega tudo e dps organiza e aplica os css e carrega os scripts.

Cara faz assim, coloca um display:none no body, na mão mesmo, nada de JS, e no document.ready vc remove esse display:none.

Entendeu?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/uoLp26f4/
fiz um exemplo pra vc ver